# Grails GORM query multiple cascading one to many relationship levels

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In Grails I have these 4 domain classes:

```
package com.whatever.ts4

class A_class {
   String aName
   static hasMany = [b_class: B_class]
}

package com.whatever.ts4

class B_class {
   String bName
   A_class a_class
   static hasMany = [c_class: C_class]
   static belongsTo = [A_class]
}

package com.whatever.ts4

class C_class {
   String cName
   B_class b_class
   static hasMany = [d_class: D_class]
   static belongsTo = [B_class]
}

package com.whatever.ts4

class D_class {
   Long rowNumber
   String dataValue 
   C_class c_class
   static belongsTo = [C_class]  
}
```

Simple ER diagram:
A_class 1=>many B_class 1=>many C_class 1=>many D_class

I'm successfully populating them in BootStrap.groovy

Now,given an single A_class id, I need to obtain a set with these columns:

aName, bName, cName, rowNumber, dataValue

Can I do that using namedQueries?

I’ve tried putting this in the A_class domain class:

```
static namedQueries = {
   myNamedQuery { aid ->          
      createAlias b_class,'b'
      createAlias 'b.c_class','c'
      createAlias 'c.d_class','d'         
      eq 'id',aid
   }
}
```

I like the idea of a named query, because this result set will need to be returned for different A_class id’s. I can utilize a Service to prep the data and call it via the Controller which will render it as JSON (I digress). But, perhaps there is a Groovier way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need named query for this kind of action. You will obtain all information that you need just by taking it from A_class entity. For example:

```
def a_class_entity = A_class.get(id) 
def b_names = a_class_entity.b_class.bName // set of all bNames 

//<-- Not sure if flatten() works with spread collection fields, but it should -->
def c_names = a_class_entity.b_class.c_class.flatten().cName // collection of all cNames
def rowNumbers = a_class_entity.b_class.c_class.d_class.flatten().rowNumber // collection of all rowNumbers 
def dataValues = a_class_entity.b_class.c_class.d_class.flatten().dataValue // collection of all dataValues
```

Comment: Araxn1d, that's getting each piece. I need to get it into a properly related map so that I can "render resultSet as JSON". This data is going down to a Single Page App which will display the resultSet and allow active filtering.  I'm getting close to having the plain-jane SQL working. But I'd like to understand how to do it with a Groovy/Grais/GORM approach.